# Matching observers to specific targets in Construct Sight Line using 3D Analyst with ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d-analyst, visibility

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.8 with its 3D Analyst extension.

I used the Construct Sight Line tool for 37 observation points relative to 748 target point features. I would like to match the observation points to specific target points within a limited distance. I don't want a sight line to EVERY target from EVERY observer. I don't understand how to use the (optional) Join_Field aspect of this tool, and the Sampling Distance option is meant for line and polygon targets (both of my data sets are point).

Can anyone explain to me what the Join_Field aspect of the Construct Sight Line tool does and how to deploy it?

I checked in with ArcMap Help which says "The join field is used to match observers to specific targets." The default value is : —No Z values will be assigned to the resulting sight line features."

Esri online help repeats the exact same description https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/construct-sight-lines.htm

The Python sample script shows:    join_field = "#"
(I don't know what that means and I'm not trying to deploy the tool with Python.. not that good yet...)

Comment: What does its online help say about this parameter?  I think you should include a link to that and say why it is not helping you.

Comment: Edited as suggested.